# deeptools k-means clustering

Tags: heatmap, bioinformatics

I have a straightforward query related to my ChIP-seq data analysis. I utilized deepTools' plotHeatmap function and applied k-means clustering to generate a heatmap. Now, I'm seeking assistance in identifying the peaks associated with each cluster. It's worth noting that I initially asked this question on Biostars.org without receiving a response (https://www.biostars.org/p/9581460/).

Could anyone kindly provide guidance on how to extract information about which peaks belong to each cluster?

Additionally, I can share a relevant code snippet if that would be helpful

Thank you in advance!

code snippet:

```
computeMatrix reference-point -p 28 --referencePoint TSS -b 1000 -a 1000 -R ./e.bed -S ./bigwig/HCC_Input_R1.bigWig ./bigwig/HCC_JUN_R1.bigWig ./bigwig/HCC_JUN_R2.bigWig  --skipZeros -o ./matrix.mat.gz 

plotHeatmap -m matrix.mat.gz -out 1kbTSS_135ps.png --colorMap Purples --kmeans 4 --outFileNameMatrix ./1kbTSS_135ps.gz
```

I created heatmap using this code and applied k-means clustering